# Are there any cards capable of modifying the mana symbols?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Are there any cards - old ones, or newest ones - capable of modifying the mana symbols?

For example [Shivan Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=469888) has the ability "{R}: Shivan Dragon gets +1/+0 until end of turn". Can this ability be transformed, for example, into "{W}: Shivan Dragon gets +1/+0 until end of turn"?

It should be noted that, obviously, I am not referring to either "[Sleight of Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSleight%20of%20Mind%5d)" card - which can only modify the text of a card containing a color, but not mana symbols - nor to "[Magical Hack](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=3922)" card - which is able to modify the basic land types, but not mana symbols.

[Crimson Hellkite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrimson%20Hellkite%5d) has an ability that uses the phrase "red mana". In a case like this, would Sleight of Mind be enough to change the type of mana required in the Helkite's activated ability?

Comment: Re "*Are there any cards capable of modifying the mana symbols?*", The answer to this is yes. Copy effects such as Clone's can change the *mana cost*, effectively replacing the mana symbols with different ones. But that's not really what you're asking about.

Comment: I disagree with your view, Ikegami. I think I explained myself enough. I'm not talking about mana cost, but rather more situations in which there is a certain mana symbol on the text of a given card,just like on activated abilities. Just as the two blue cards mentioned in the body of the question are able to modify colors, or basic land types, I was looking - if it exists - for a card that is capable of even modifying mana symbols. if it doesn't exist ... well, too bad, I'll make it a reason!

Comment: You didn't read what I said, did you? Reread the last sentence. My comment was specifically not addressed to you.

Comment: "Re "Are there any cards capable of modifying the mana symbols?", The answer to this is yes. Copy effects such as Clone's can change the mana cost, effectively replacing the mana symbols with different ones. But that's not really what you're asking about".Aren't you the one who wrote these things Ikegami? Well, if so, I'm sorry, but your comment is just below my question, so how can you say it's not addressed to me? but how much you enjoy yourself with your "shortcuts" ... and your artificial misunderstandings

Comment: This site is built on the premise that Q&A are to help future readers. How arrogant of you to think it's all about you. And then insist on it when told otherwise. Twice I've told you I wasn't answering your real question but the one in the title in the original comment, You know, because someone might actually be looking for the answer to that question. Please stop insulting me for trying to help others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the actual mana symbols; however there are cards that would allow you spend mana "as though" it were another color. [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d) is one example. Among other things, it has:

> Players may spend mana as though it were mana of any color.

With this in play, you could spend any color of mana to activate [Shivan Dragon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShivan%20Dragon%5d)'s ability.

[Celestial Dawn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCelestial%20Dawn%5d) would allow you to spend white mana as though it were any color; [Sunglasses of Urza](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSunglasses%20of%20Urza%5d) allows you to spend white mana specifically as though it were red mana.

[Sleight of Mind](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSleight%20of%20Mind%5d) would allow you to change the text of [Crimson Hellkite](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCrimson%20Hellkite%5d); it refers to "red mana"; so you can change that text to something like "white mana".

Note that in general; gaining access to other colors of mana is called "mana fixing". It can be in the form of lands or other objects that can add multiple colors of mana; or objects that allow you to spend one type of mana to get another type. You can read all about it here: https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Mana_fixing.

Comment: I just want to mention that the original printing of Celestial Dawn did what he was asking for (changed mana symbols).  It seems like they would never do that at this point since they have the "Spend...as though it were..." type of templates that don't get into text changing weirdness.

Comment: There's also another part of the question about whether Sleight of Mind can affect the mana required for Crimson Helkite's ability.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Before your edit; I misread it and thought he was asking about Shivan Dragon.

Comment: Gendolkari, it is true: I explained myself not enough, and you understood I' m talking about the Shivan Dragon in the last part of the question too. Murgatroid's edit works better than my original question

Comment: Please, it is important to note that - in my opinion - assuming that it is possible for the "Sleight of mind" card to profitably modify the text of Crimson Hellkite, the operation is really unfair, since it concerns precisely the mana and its symbol, and not the color itself. Card Authors had to do this because - in my opinion - since Hellkite has to tap himself to activate his ability, they could not simply write it like an "inflatable ability", i.e. this way - R: Hellkite deals 1 damage to a creature.

Comment: @Massimiliano It is likely true that this is a random side-effect of the way things had to be done, rather than an intended interaction. But I don't see how that makes it "unfair"; MTG contains huge amounts of interactions such as this one where things just happened to work out that way.

Comment: Well, it is true. Anyway, I'm waiting for other answers - if them will come - because it is a weird interaction, and I'd like to read what people think about this oddity...No doubt about what you say it's true, but you have to admit that this is really what generally cannot be performed with Sleight of mind: that is, changing the mana color.

Comment: Your answer is good, Gendolkari. But there is still some doubt: are you really sure, Gendolkari, that the operation indicated in your answer is correct? Some other players may find the operation completely wrong, or arbitrary. After all, it is one of those weird interactions, which will certainly happen often. This is why I am waiting a little longer, before accepting the good response received.

Comment: @Massimiliano Which interaction are you questioning; the Crimson Hellkite / Slight of Mind one? I don't see where there is room for doubt... the card says to replace all instances of one color word with a different color word; so you can replace the word "red" with the word "white".

Comment: But it is true, as I have already told you,Gendolkari, it is so. I'm just waiting if some other user wants to have his say, and maybe he thinks it differently than you... and me, since I agree with you.

Comment: However, what emerged here allows a player with "Sleight of Mind" card in his hands to actually change the color of the mana - and its symbol, to all intents and purposes - whenever a formula of the type "[any one color] mana" occurs in the texts of the cards. Such as, in addition to the Crimson Hellkite, also in the Mirrodin card "Consume Spirit", and some others. Good stuff.